# How to solve this system of differential equations? it seems that $x$ is depending from $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve the system:

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> tx'(t)=x(t)+y(t),\\ 
> ty'(t)=3x(t)-y(t).
> \end{cases}
> $$

No initial conditions were given or anything like that, that's it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Agree that you should show your work before anyone helps you; disagree that this should be closed as "off-topic". It's clearly "on-topic", the topic being differential equations.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the two equations yields
$$t(x'+y')=4x$$
Differentiating the first equation yields
$$x'+tx''=x'+y'$$
Using the second to substitute for $x'+y'$ in the first yields
$$t(x'+tx'')=4x$$
which can be solved in the form $x=ax^{n_1}+bx^{n_2}$

Comment: One could also mention "Euler-Cauchy equation" along with the solution form.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply. How do I actually do the last part "x=ax^(n1)+bx^(n2)" what are the steps ?

Answer (score 3):

> **Avoiding any tricks**, the best is clearly to diagonalize the matrix on the right.

Note that
$$
S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 3 & -1\end{pmatrix}S=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\quad\text{where}\quad
S=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\ 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
(simply compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors).
So in the new variables
$$
\begin{pmatrix} z\\w\end{pmatrix}=S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}, \tag 1
$$
the original equation
$$
t\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 3 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}
$$
can be written in the form
$$
t\begin{pmatrix} z\\w\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} z\\w\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So you need to solve
$$
tz'=-2z\quad\text{and}\quad tw'=2w.
$$
After that you can recover $x$ and $y$ from $(1)$.

Comment: "tz′=−2z and tw′=2w" could you explain me what to do from this point and how to solv it actually? edit: thank you for your earlier reply.

Comment: Write $z'/z=-2/t$ and integrate on both sides. The same for the second equation, write $w'/w=2/t$ and integrate.

Comment: By integrating both sides I get z=t^(-2) and w=t^(2), if it is right, am I supposed to put it the back in (1)? If yes, how can solve the part (1)?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices?

Comment: yes, I will multiply S^(-1) which is (1 1; 3 -1) with (x y), and after that I am going to multiply what I get with z and w value?

Comment: Exactly, you need to go back to $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

we get $$tx''=x'+y'$$ so we get
$$tx''=x'+\frac{3}{t}x-\frac{1}{t}y$$ and with your first equation
$$tx''=x'+\frac{3}{t}x-\frac{1}{t}(tx'-x)$$

Comment: $tx'=x+y\implies tx''+x'=x'+y'$

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new variable $\tau=\ln{t}$, then
$$t\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{d\tau}$$
Thus you get a linear system with constant coefficients in variable $\tau$. I assume you know how to proceed...